# Can this hide columns code be written more efficiently?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm newbie in writing VBA codes - I will be geatfull if you could advice me how to write this hide column code more efficiently:

The purpose of the code is: If the cell in column **F4** is **empty** then hide the column **F** and so on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("F4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("G4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("H4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("I4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("J4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("K4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("L4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("M4").Value = "" Then
    Columns("M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems strange to be hiding columns whenever there is a `Change` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop across columns 6 to 13 might improve things:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 6 To 13
        Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(4, c).Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I like how the `.Hidden` is based on `IsEmpty()`, since that'll return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, instead of using another `IF` statement. I really need to learn/pay more attention in my macros and do stuff like that, very efficient!

Comment: @BruceWayne - I originally had that line as `... = Cells(4, c).Value = ""` (which also returns `True` or `False`), but saw the word "empty" in the question and decided that `IsEmpty` was a more appropriate way of coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:-

```
Sub Hide_Columns()
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("F4:K4").Cells
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks:-)

Comment: I'm trying to extend the VBA code - but the second part does not work, any idea why? `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Long
    Dim delta As Long
    For c = 6 To 13
        Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(4, c).Value)
    Next
    For delta = 17 To 22
        Columns(delta).EntireColumn.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(4, c).Value)
    Next
End Sub`